# why is "else" on the trigger considered wrong?

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I wrote the following code

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER bm_keuangan 
AFTER UPDATE ON pembayaran_project FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE nama_project varchar(100);
DECLARE cek_di_keuangan varchar(100);
IF (!(isnull(NEW.deleted_at))) THEN
    UPDATE keuangan SET keuangan.deleted_at = now() WHERE keuangan.ref = NEW.id AND keuangan.jk_id = 5;
ELSE

END IF;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

And I got error :

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'END IF;
>
> END' at line 10

Comment: Because you are not doing anything in the else block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ELSE block is empty, this is not allowed in mysql. You should remove the keyword ELSE from your code, as follows :

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER bm_keuangan 
AFTER UPDATE ON pembayaran_project FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE nama_project varchar(100);
DECLARE cek_di_keuangan varchar(100);
IF (!(isnull(NEW.deleted_at))) THEN
    UPDATE keuangan SET keuangan.deleted_at = now() WHERE keuangan.ref = NEW.id AND keuangan.jk_id = 5;

END IF;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

From [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html) (emphasis mine):

> ```
> IF search_condition THEN statement_list
>     [ELSEIF search_condition THEN statement_list] ...
>     [ELSE statement_list]
> END IF
> ```
>
> Each `statement_list` consists of one or more SQL statements; **an empty `statement_list` is not permitted**.